# Como establecer un limite de días al seleccionar una fecha en calendario con javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datetimepicker

Tengo estos dos campos de tipo fecha, que los utilizo para establecer un periodo de fechas

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input id="fechInicio"  name="fechInicio" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
  <input id="fechFin"  name="fechFin" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que en el primer calendario, que es fechaInicio me permita seleccionar hasta dos meses atrás de la fecha actual, no más

y que en el segundo calendario que es la fecha fin, No me deje seleccionar el día anterior al seleccionado en el primer calendario y que pueda seleccionar hasta dos meses después de la fecha actual

tengo este código, pero solo inicializa las fechas,

```html
function validaFechas(){

 $('datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false
 
 });
 
 $('datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false
 
 });

}
```

como puedo hacer esas validaciones?

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que setear `minDate` y `maxDate` en las opciones del `datepicker`.

> minDate  Type: Date or Number or String Default: null The minimum
>   selectable date. When set to null, there is no minimum.
>
> Multiple types supported:
>
> ```
> Date: A date object containing the minimum date.
> Number: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
> String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period
> ```
>
> pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks,
>   and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and
>   seven days from today.

[Puedes ver detalles aquí](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Ejemplo en el primero seleccionas la fecha mínima y en al cerrarlo cambias las fechas para el que segundo datepicker empiece un día después de lo seleccionado en el primero y lo muestras:

```
$('datepicker1').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
      format: 'L',
      useCurrent: false,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      minDate: new Date('2018-04-15'),
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var date2 = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", date2);
            window.setTimeout(function(){$('#datepicker2').datepicker('show')},50);
          }

    });
```

Del mismo modo que se setea minDate se puede modificar maxDate.